# Why I get extra white space under UITableViewHeaderView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: Here is the screenshot: [Screenshot][1]]

I've created my own HeaderView class and set tableView default HeaderView to it:

```
class MyHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and later I'm using it in my delegate:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView as! MyHeaderView
    headerView.countLabel.text = "Something here"

    return headerView
}
```

and also I set the height for it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 63.0
}
```

but as you can see in the image, I get extra space under the HeaderView line. When I set the `heightForHeaderInSection` to 0.0, everything goes back to normal, but in that case my `viewForHeaderInSection` will not be run and my label will not change. Can someone point to my mistake?

**UPDATE**

I also get this Constraint conflict there:

`"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001874cd0 UILabel:0x7fbfeb61cdb0'0 repository results'.height == 24   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001876440 V:|-(24)-[UILabel:0x7fbfeb61cdb0'0 repository results']   (active, names: '|':GitHub.SearchHeaderView:0x7fbfeb61c700 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000018764e0 V:[UILabel:0x7fbfeb61cdb0'0 repository results']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':GitHub.SearchHeaderView:0x7fbfeb61c700 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001875040 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' GitHub.SearchHeaderView:0x7fbfeb61c700.height == 63   (active)>"`

Comment: Have you used autolayout in MyHeaderView?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR MyHeaderView is only a class, without `xib` file

Comment: But you have a iboutlet in that class?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR yes, `countLabel: UILabel`

Comment: Without xib or storyboard how can you have iboutlet?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR ah, sorry! You are right! I've connected directly from Storyboard. Also I've updated my question. I get these constraint conflicts there